# Importing module item of subpackage from another subpackage

Tags: python, package

I have this project structure:

```
root_package/
root_package/packA/
root_package/packA/__init__.py (empty)
root_package/packA/moduleA.py
root_package/packB/__init__.py (empty)
root_package/packB/moduleB.py
root_package/rootModule.py
```

In the `rootModule.py` I have `from packA.moduleA import ModuleAClass`.
At the `packA.moduleA.py` I have this `from root_package.packB.moduleB import ModuleBItem`.

When running rootModule either via PyCharm or the terminal with `python ./rootModule.py` I am getting this error:

Was this the right way of importing?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_dir/rootPackage/rootModule.py", line 7, in <module>
    from packA.moduleA import ModuleAClass
  File "/project_dir/rootPackage/packA/moduleA.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rootPackage.packB.moduleB import module_b_method
  File "/project_dir/rootPackage/rootModule.py", line 7, in <module>
    from packA.wavelet_compression import WaveletCompression
ImportError: cannot import name WaveletCompression
```

How to solve this?

**Update 1**
I've added a test file at the *project_folder* (**not** the root_package folder).
So the current directory structure is this:

```
project_folder/
project_folder/root_package/
project_folder/root_package/packA/
project_folder/root_package/packA/__init__.py (empty)
project_folder/root_package/packA/moduleA.py
project_folder/root_package/packB/__init__.py (empty)
project_folder/root_package/packB/moduleB.py
project_folder/root_package/rootModule.py
project_folder/test_rootModule.py
```

I haven't made the `project_folder` a package (no `__init__.py` file) since, the `test_rootModule` is simply a script to help me run the experiments.

So, in `root_package/packA/moduleA.py`, after changing the `from root_package.packB.moduleB import ModuleBitem`, to `from packB.moduleB import ModuleBitem`, as the answer suggests, it works.

But now there are **two** problems:
1. PyCharm doesn't agree with the change:
[image: pycharm-import-error]

2. I cannot run my experiments from the `project_folder/test_rootModule.py` script. 
   I got this error:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "project_folder/test_rootModule.py", line 8, in 
       from root_package.rootModule import rootModuleClass
     File "project_folder/root_package/rootModule.py", line 7, in 
       from packA.moduleA import ModuleAClass
     File "project_folder/root_package/packA/moduleA.py", line 8, in 
       from packB.moduleB import module_b_item
   ImportError: No module named packB.moduleB

*I cannot seem to get the 2nd Traceback to look like a code segment.*

**Update 2**

What solved the problem was going to the `Project: project_name > Project Structure` dialog in PyCharm, selecting the `root_package` and then setting it as a `Sources` folder.
Now, I can run via the IDE both the `rootModule` and the `test_rootModule`.

**Although**, I cannot get to run the `test_rootModule` from the terminal. 
The `test_rootModule` has these imports:

```
from root_package.rootModule import RootModuleClass
from root_package.packB.moduleB import module_b_item
```

I am at the `project_folder` dir, and run `python ./test_rootModule.py` and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_rootModule.py", line 8, in <module>
    from root_package.rootModule import RootModuleClass
  File "project_folder/root_package/rootModule.py", line 7, in <module>
    from packA.moduleA import ModuleAClass
  File "project_folder/root_package/packA/moduleA.py", line 8, in <module>
    from packB.moduleB import module_b_item
ImportError: No module named packB.moduleB
```

Comment: does importing from any other module in packA work?

Comment: @idjaw All the other modules in packA use the module_b_method, so I get the same result.

Comment: hmm...Try changing this `from root_package.packB.moduleB import ` to this `from packB.moduleB import `

Answer (score 1):

If you are running all your code from within this path:

`project_folder`

Then you should ensure that all your modules that reside in `root_package` are referenced by that first. So for example:

`from root_package.modA import foo`

Comment: Although this worked, it created some other problems.  Also, it seems PyCharm doesn't like the change (I've included a screen shot at my OP).

Comment: I've added another update to my OP, could you please take a look?

Comment: So, to focus on the command line. For this `from root_package.rootModule import RootModuleClass`. If you are running your code within 'root_package', you cannot set your module import as such. The root of execution does not know of root_package at all.

Comment: There just seems to be a bit of a mess going on between what you are configuring to run in Pycharm and your expectation of where you are running in the command-prompt. It would be so much easier if I were sitting next to you :P . We will get this working ;)

Comment: I am running the `test_rootModule` script from the `project_folder` (the `root_package` is a subfolder of `project_folder`), that's why I've included the `from root_package.rootModule import RootModuleClass`. That is true :P Thank you for your help so far idjaw! Hope we can figure this out

Comment: You're very weclome. I've been through these very problems...I get it. So, just to get things clear. The way things are configured in PyCharm, everything works perfectly fine right? You are now strictly facing problems with the command-line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90642/discussion-between-chris-and-idjaw).